# How to have own string class with no public constructor?

Tags: c++, string, oop

I am trying to declare my own `String` class which mimics the std::string class. Below is the `String` class.

```
class String {
    public:
        // Copy constructor.
        String(const String &);
        // Conversion to std::string.
        operator std::string() const;
        // Assignment.
        String &operator=(const String &);
};
```

One of the constraints that I have is this:

> There is *no need for a public constructor*, though you would need a
>   private (or undocumented one). Also, note that this `String` class
>   will allow us to use optimized memory management.

I am confused by the highlighted lines. I tried to implement as follows:

```
class String: public std::string {
    private:
        String();
        String *s;
    public:

        // Copy constructor.
        String(const String &a) {
            s = a.s;
        };
        // Conversion to std::string.
        operator std::string() const {
            return this;
        };
        // Assignment.
        String& operator=(const String &a) {
            if(this != &a) {
                s=a.s;
            }
            return *this;
        };
};
```

But I am facing problem with this approach as this is wrong. What am I doing wrong and what is the right method to implement it?

The main problem is in converting my `String` object to `std::string`. How to do this? `return this` line gives me an error.

Comment: Don't inherit from classes without a virtual destructor.

Comment: what "problem" are you facing?

Comment: @chris I took out most of the other code to make the question simpler.

Comment: Where are you storing you actual char * or whatever represents in your internal data?

Comment: @user93353 I want the base class to handle that.

Comment: @chris no problem inheriting from standard types with virtual vtors privately, as long as you never expose a pointer to your base class subobject.

Comment: @StephenLin, Yeah, it's a lot more work to go into detail about this and the OP definitely isn't inheriting privately. It's good general advice and there's rarely a time you need to subvert it.

Comment: i know, it's just that you made a blanket statement...no worries

Comment: s/with virtual vtors/without virtual dtors/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is generally bad practice to inherit from a class like `std::string` for a few reasons, including the fact it has a non-virtual destructor, so someone can have a pointer to `std::string` and not realize it is actually a pointer to you, delete it, and your destructor will never be called.

Your class has state, so it needs a destructor, so inheriting from `std::string` is not allowed.

To fix your immediate compile error, `return *this;` works.  You are, however, asking the wrong question.

Do *not* do this: `class String: public std::string` ever.  (well, almost ever -- I could construct a justification, but it wouldn't be a good one)

Comment: Not only is your constructor not called, but the behaviour is undefined if the destructor is not virtual, whether it has state or not

Comment: `class String: private std::string` is probably fine though, if you do it carefully.